# Is there a way to change the size of the box form that I made, can the form also be on the right while I have left side text?

Tags: html, css

How can I make it so not only my form is small but it is on the right had side and I can put text on the left side. I couldn't find anything on google so I tried this.
I tried to align the form but it only works for images.

```
#questions > .question, #languages > .language{
margin: auto;
overflow: auto;
padding: 8px;
width: 75%;
}
.choices > .choice, #languages > .language{
background: #ffffff;
border-radius: 8px;

opacity: 0.7;
overflow: auto;
padding: 16px;
}
#questions, #languages{
margin-bottom: 48px;
}
#languages > .language{
margin-top: 8px;
}
.language > img{
float: left;
margin-right: 24px;
padding: 
}
```

This only works for images with `SRC` not with actual forms

Comment: you need to show your html as well as your css before anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: its too long but...

Comment: it is too long by 10000 characters\

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i understand that you want form on the right side and text on the left side.
then make a container first in html, after make two div's. one for form and one for content.
then use width 50% and float left;

Here's the link - [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/guloqubuva/edit?html,css,output)

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    this is the content part
  </div>
  <div class="form">
    <form>
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="text"/>
      <input type="text"/>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
```

css:

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.content,.form{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.form input{
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: put some media queries, like if screen `max-width: 360px` then make float: none and for look good make 50% to 100% for full-width, it'll cover the screen.
This is the updated link - [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/jeviquxezi/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change form such that labels on right and text on left , through transforming the scale on whole form and then on individual element to make it readable. It is demonstrated in below code:

```css
.flip
{
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1);
}

.fName
{
    width:90px;
    height:30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.formBox
{
    width:700px;
    height: 500px;
    background:grey;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="flip">
   <form class="formBox" action = "/cgi-bin/hello_get.cgi" method = "get">
  <div class="fName flip"> 
  First name 
  </div>
            <input type = "text" class="flip" name = "first_name" value = "" maxlength = "100" />
         <br />
   
   <div class="fName flip"> 
   Last name 
   </div>
  
  
            <input type = "text" class="flip" name = "last_name" value = "" maxlength = "100" />
         <input type = "submit" class="flip" value ="Submit" />
   </form>
 </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

And for changing size of form : declare height width of form element ,then
resize other element inside form using % measure.

Comment: if you have any further query please share